# How can I unwind multiple connections from with?

Tags: optimization, neo4j

I'm 99% complete with my query but just have to optimize it now. In the query below the number of `Media`'s having relation `WITH` for tag `target` *and* `tag` is calculation twice. Once in the first match when I do `count(r)` and secondly at `WHERE media-[:WITH]->(target) WITH COUNT(*)`. I would like to optimize the query to pass the counts from the first match down and correlate it with each tag so that I do not have to calculate this value twice. How can I pass 2 collections and unwind them? Or if there is any other way to save on this duplicate calculation I'd love to hear it.

Sample console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=26vqyk

```
MATCH (target:Tag {name:'tagName'})<-[:WITH]-(:Media)-[r:WITH]->(tag:Tag)
WITH count(r) as counts, tag, target
ORDER BY counts DESC LIMIT 100
WITH collect(tag) as tags, target
UNWIND tags as tag
MATCH (m:Media)-[r:WITH]->(tag)
WITH count(r) as totes, collect(m) as medias, target, tag.name as tag
UNWIND medias as media
MATCH media
WHERE media-[:WITH]->(target)
WITH COUNT(*) as both, totes, tag
RETURN tag, both, totes, both/(totes*1.0)*100
ORDER BY both DESC LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you collect the tags first and then unwind immediately after?
Esp. as you never use tags again?

Some idea:

```
MATCH (target:Tag {name:'tagName'})<-[r1:WITH]-(:Media)-[r2:WITH]->(tag:Tag)
WITH count(distinct r2) as tagCounts, count(distinct r1) as mediaCounts, tag, target
ORDER BY mediaCounts DESC LIMIT 100
MATCH (m:Media)-[r:WITH]->(tag)
WITH count(r) as totes, size((m)-[:WITH]->(target)) as both, 
     target, tag.name as tag, mediaCounts, tagCounts
....
```

Comment: I unwind because I have to run a query on each of the tags and the only way to do that is to first collect and then unwind. What does the mediaCounts return in your query? count(r1) & count(r2) are both the same number.